# SurfaceView height and width

Tags: android, height, width, surfaceview

I am wondering how to take a

```
SurfaceView
```

class that I have made and get the height and the width of the surface from the SurfaceView's constructor. (Height and Width in pixels)

I believe this should be really easy, but it is turning out quite hard.

I know Google discourages using the height and width properties but I feel that I need them.

Any help would be appreciated,
Thanks!

Comment: If you can determine the size that the SurfaceView will be, you could pass that in a custom constructor, but you'd need to create the SurfaceView dynamically; i.e., not in layout xml. Otherwise, a View doesn't know its size until it's being laid out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SurfaceView doesn't quite work that way.

The SurfaceView has two parts, the Surface and the View.  The View is created by the view hierarchy, and is subject to the usual layout mechanics.

The Surface is created by the Window Manager.  This requires an IPC to the graphics compositor (SurfaceFlinger).  Because of the potential for delay, the SurfaceView instantiation has an asynchronous component, and the Surface will generally not exist until after the SurfaceView constructor exits.

The correct way to deal with this is to set up the [SurfaceHolder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceHolder.html#addCallback(android.view.SurfaceHolder.Callback)) callbacks and wait for the `surfaceChanged()` method to be called.  The callback accepts the surface width and height as arguments.

You can see some examples in [Grafika](https://github.com/google/grafika), e.g. the "[hardware scaler exerciser](https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/src/com/android/grafika/HardwareScalerActivity.java)" activity tracks changes to the width and height.

Answer (score 1):

Try Like this:

`getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
 Width = metrics.widthPixels;
 Height = metrics.heightPixels;`

Comment: Does this go in the constructor of the SurfaceView?

Comment: That gets you the display size.  The Surface size may be different because of screen decorations (status and nav bars).